# How to reference a file in html using .. or absolute address

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I write this url so that it pulls from whatever copy I am working on? If on localhost I want it to pull from my local file structure. Then when loaded on the server it should pull from its own directory

This pulls from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://www.myapp.com/JS/HelperFunctions.js"></script>
```

This pulls from the localhost, but when loaded on the server it breaks:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "../JS/HelperFunctions.js"></script>
```

How do I format it so I don't have to change it whether on local or server? and it pulls from that source?

Comment: I want it to find the folder no matter if it is on my local machine or on the server...

Comment: Use a relative URL starting at the root. So try `src="/JS/HelperFunctions.js"`. If you're not sure of the root (like in case it's loaded at `www.myapp.com/someapp/`, then you need to use your server code to figure that out. Unless you're attempting to get a resource from a different domain/site than what's running, you should be using relative URLs

Comment: just use `./JS/HelperFunctions.js`

Comment: can you add the link to the page on the server?  it will help us debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ian suggested try just using the relative URL from the root. So an example of this would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/JS/HelperFunctions.js"></script>
```

That's assuming that your JS folder is in the root folder.

By having this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "../JS/HelperFunctions.js"></script>
```

You are basically telling the page to go back a folder then go into the JS folder and find the actual file. If you have that on the root index.html it won't work properly. However that will work on any tier 2 pages. For example, `http://www.website.com/about/`

Comment: Failed to load resource file:///JS/HelperFunctions.js:0   Structure is  this:  Root --> index.html, Folder2, JS.   JS --> HelperFunctions.js

Comment: Is your JS folder inside of Folder2?

Comment: Do you have to work locally? Are you running a local server? It's hard to understand the problem with what you've told us. Is it possible to load to a live server?

Answer (score -2):

You omit the protocol part of the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "//JS/HelperFunctions.js"></script>
```

This way, the browser would use the same protocol as the page (http:// or file://).

Comment: Protocol has nothing to do with this question

Comment: @ryan Until the OP clarify's his question, we can never know. He can always use a relative url, but it looks like he already tried that (in his second example).